# Match the last group of (potentially) nested brackets

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to match the **last** group, which is enclosed in `[]`, but may contain one of more `[]` inside of itself in a nested structure.

I managed, although not elegantly, to get the nested `[]` matching going using the `regex` of `python`. This solution works for some cases (such as `s1`) but not `s2` or `s3` when there are multiple such matches. My solution will only match the first one.

Any suggestions? A better regular expression? Or regular expression is not the way to go? Thanks a lot!

```
In [116]:

s1 = 'AAA [BBB [CCC]]'
s2 = 'AAA [DDD] [EEE]'
s3 = 'AAA [BBB [CCC]] [EEE]'

for s in [s1, s2, s3]:
    result = regex.search(r'(?<rec>\[(?:[^\[\]]++|(?&rec))*\])',s,flags=regex.VERBOSE)
    print(result.captures('rec'))
['[CCC]', '[BBB [CCC]]'] #I know it is perfect, but I can take the last one in the list
['[DDD]'] #This is the first one, I want the last one, which is [EEE]
['[CCC]', '[BBB [CCC]]'] #same problem as above
```

## Edit:

Thanks a lot of the help, if I have 15 reps I will up-vote ya all. However, sorry for not including the intended result, which should be:

```
'AAA [BBB [CCC]]' -> '[BBB [CCC]]'
'AAA [DDD] [EEE]' -> '[EEE]'
'AAA [BBB [CCC]] [EEE]' -> '[EEE]'
'000 [[aaa] xxx [yyy [zzz ]]' -> '[[aaa] xxx [yyy [zzz ]]'
```

Comment: You can in fact accomplish this with look aheads/behinds however, I would likely make use of a stack/parser in this type of situation.

Comment: @Vlad, he has a nested structure. That may be why he has recursive regex here, I am not not sure that look around alone will do, but correct me if I am wrong. Welcome to SO, OP!

Comment: what output do you want?

Comment: Is `[[aaa] xxx [yyy [zzz ]]` a possible situation? i.e. A mixture of different level of nested structure.

Comment: FYI added tested Python code. :)

Comment: @CTZhu, a good point I haven't though about, but `000 [[aaa] xxx [yyy [zzz ]]` should yield `[[aaa] xxx [yyy [zzz ]]`, see edit:

Comment: Glad it works! FYI also added regex for more complex nests like `Added regex for more complex nests like `[B[C] [D] [E[F][G]]]` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, to use recursion or repeated subroutines, we need to use Matthew Barnett's outstanding [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module... And, as @CTZhu points out, you are already using it!

To be clear on terms, there can be several understandings of "nesting", such as:

1. **Simple nesting** as in `[C[D[E]F]]`, which is a subset of...
2. **More complex, family-style nesting** as in `[B[C] [D] [E[F][G]]]`.

You need to be able to handle the latter, and this short regex does it for us:

```
\[(?:[^[\]]++|(?R))*\]
```

This will match all the nested braces. Now all we need to do is print the last match.

**Here is some tested Python code:**

```
import regex # say "yeah!" for Matthew Barnett
pattern = r'\[(?:[^[\]]++|(?R))*\]'
myregex = regex.compile(pattern)

# this outputs [EEE]
matches = myregex.findall('AAA [BBB [CCC]] [EEE]')
print (matches[-1])

# this outputs [C[D[E]F]] (simple nesting)
matches = myregex.findall('AAA [BBB] [C[D[E]F]]')
print (matches[-1])

# this outputs [B[C] [D] [E[F][G]]] (family-style nesting)
matches = myregex.findall('AAA [AAA] [B[]B[B]] [B[C] [D] [E[F][G]]]')
print (matches[-1])
```

Comment: +1 for the (that I think) right answer. But you missed the fact that OP is already using `regex`, see `regex.search`? Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the prefect solution! I will study the demo you provided to understand it better.

Comment: @CTZhu Thanks, hadn't noticed that! Added regex for more complex nests like `[B[C] [D] [E[F][G]]]` :)

Comment: +1, Wonderful! Thanks a lot for your help @zx81. Especially for the B solution, which I have not even considered before! And I am reading your answer that has a score of 88, very impressive!

Comment: @user3732025 Thanks for the great question, hope to see you again! :)

Comment: Great solution! You do not need, however, to use `matches[len(matches)-1]` Just do `matches[-1]` for the last element, `matches[-2]` for second to last, etc.

Comment: @dawg Indeed! As you can see I'm still learning Python. Thanks very much, made the edit, that's an improvement. :)

Comment: @user3732025 FYI improved the regex, shorter and better. :)

Comment: This regex with the final example of `'000 [[aaa] xxx [yyy [zzz ]]'` produces `[yyy [zzz ]]` which is incomplete and unbalanced braces.

Comment: @dawg Is that a new example that wasn't there yesterday? I'm adding digits for Opening and Closing so you can see the problem with what you want. -> 'O1[O2[aaaC1] xxx O3[yyy O4[zzz C2]C3]' That's 4 opening braces and 3 closing ones. In contrast, look at the one you accuse of being incomplete and unbalanced: `O1[yyy O2[zzz C1]C2]` The pattern simply matches the last balanced brace in the whole string (the first one is `[aaa]`. We've assumed that your whole strings are balanced. If that's not the case, it's another problem (which can be solved with another similar regex). :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this recursive regex, and just print the last match:

```
s1 = 'AAA [BBB [CCC]]'
s2 = 'AAA [DDD] [EEE]'
s3 = 'AAA [BBB [CCC]] [EEE]'

import regex

for e in (s1, s2, s3):
    matches=regex.findall(r'[^\[\]\s]+ | \[ (?: (?R) | [^\[\]]+ )+\]', e, regex.VERBOSE)
    print(e, '=>', matches, '=>', matches[-1])
```

Prints:

```
AAA [BBB [CCC]] => ['AAA', '[BBB [CCC]]'] => [BBB [CCC]]
AAA [DDD] [EEE] => ['AAA', '[DDD]', '[EEE]'] => [EEE]
AAA [BBB [CCC]] [EEE] => ['AAA', '[BBB [CCC]]', '[EEE]'] => [EEE]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . Actually it is a little different from the intended result and @zx81 has already provided a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Going off your *given data* and you stating you want the **last** group, I'll provide you with this recursive regex.

```
import regex

s1 = 'AAA [BBB [CCC]]'
s2 = 'AAA [DDD] [EEE]'
s3 = 'AAA [BBB [CCC]] [EEE]'

for s in [s1, s2, s3]:
    result = regex.findall(r'\[(?:[^[\]]|(?R))*\]', s)
    print result[-1]
```

Output

```
[BBB [CCC]]
[EEE]
[EEE]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But please see my edit for intended result. Cheers!